# Train keras model from generator, get the feedback for each epoch and utilize an Early stopping algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to do three things in Keras when traing a model:

1. Use Generators
2. Get the history feedback of each epoch
3. Use Early Stopping

A snippet would look something like this:

```
loss = []
acc = []
val_loss = []
val_acc = []

# Outer loop needed for getting the history of each epoch
for i in range(0,100):
    hist = model.fit_generator(train_data.flow(x_train_np,y_train_np,batch_size=8),
                               validation_data = validation_data.flow(x_val_np,y_val_np,batch_size=8),
                               epochs=1,
                               samples_per_epoch=len(x_train_np),
                               callbacks=[earlystop])
    loss.append(hist.history['loss'])
    acc.append(hist.history['acc'])
    val_loss.append(hist.history['val_loss'])
    val_acc.append(hist.history['val_acc'])
```

The loop is needed to get the feedback for each epoch. However, this will result in the continatuion of the training after earlystopping has stopped it.

So is there a way to know when early stopping has occured inside the loop, so I can break it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **steps_per_epoch** Argument of `fit_generator()`. This allows you to set your epochs >1 and you won't need the loop anymore.

Now early stopping and hist will work exactly line with the normal `fit()` call on a static dataset.

For this to work your Generator is requited to continue working after reaching the end of a epoch (meaning number of batches as defined by steps per epoch)